# Singular points and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> In each case write the principal part of the function at its isolated
>   singular point and determine whether that point is a pole, a removable
>   singular point, or an essential singular point.
>
> i)$f(z)=ze^\frac{1}{z}$   ii)$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1+z}$
>   iii)$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ iv)$f(z)=\frac{\cos z}{z}$
>   v)$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2-z)^3}$

What I did

i)$$f(z)=ze^\frac{1}{z}=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!z^{n-1}}$$ $$=z+1+\frac{1}{2!z}+\frac{1}{3!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^3}+...\frac{1}{m!z^{m-1}}+\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^{n-1}}$$
then $z_0=0$ is an essential singular point.

ii)$$lim_{z\rightarrow -1}(z+1)\frac{z^2}{z+1}=lim_{z\rightarrow -1}z^2=1$$
then $z_0=-1$ is a simple pole and $Res(f;z_0)=1$

iii)$$lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(z-0)\frac{\sin z}{z}=lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\sin z=0$$
then $z_0=0$ is a removable singular point and $Res(f;z_0)=0$

iv)$$lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(z-0)\frac{\cos z}{z}=lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\cos z=1$$
then $z_0=0$ is a simple pole and $Res(f;z_0)=1$

v)$$lim_{z\rightarrow 2}(z-2)^2\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}=1$$
then $z_0=2$ is a pole of order 2

some wrong?

Comment: Your conclusions are correct!

Comment: @Dr.MV Is there any other way to check if the point is essential singularity point without writing the series?

Comment: One way to test is to take a limit of the function as its argument approaches the singular point and take the limit of the reciprocal of the function.  If neither limit exists, then the singularity is an essential singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of showing that $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ is to take the limits

$$\lim_{z\to 0}e^{1/z} \tag1$$

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{e^{1/z}} \tag2$$

and show that neither exists.

To do this, we take the limit along the path $x=0$ to reveal that

$$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z=0+iy)=\lim_{y\to 0}e^{-i/y}=\lim_{y\to 0}(\cos (1/y)-i\sin(1/y)) \tag 3$$

Clearly the limit in $(3)$ does not exist.

Inasmuch as the corresponding analysis shows that the limit of the reciprocal of $f$ also does not exist, then we conclude that $f$ has an essential singularity.